# CodeIgniter Rest Server Integration

Tags: php, codeigniter, rest, codeigniter-restserver

I have downloaded CodeIgniter Rest Server source code from github https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver.

I have integrated as per readme document but i am getting an error of "Invalid API Key " with 403 Forbidden error when i call like htttp://www.sitename.com:81/api/key/index to generate first time new key and store into database.

Screenshot 1 :[See this screenshot of error occured in FF browser as well as in POSTMAN Extension used in Google Chrome Windows 7 - 64bit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Dtpb.png)

Below is the code in my Rest.php >>>>>

```
<?php 
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
$config['force_https'] = FALSE;
$config['rest_default_format'] = 'json';
$config['rest_supported_formats'] = ['json','array','csv','html','jsonp','php','serialized','xml'];
$config['rest_status_field_name'] = 'status';
$config['rest_message_field_name'] = 'error';
$config['enable_emulate_request'] = TRUE;
$config['rest_realm'] = 'REST API';
$config['rest_auth'] = FALSE;
$config['auth_source'] = ''; //i set it as none/blank, default value set as 'ldap'
$config['auth_library_class'] = '';
$config['auth_library_function'] = '';
$config['rest_valid_logins'] = ['admin' => '1234'];
$config['rest_ip_whitelist_enabled'] = FALSE;
$config['rest_ip_whitelist'] = '';
$config['rest_ip_blacklist_enabled'] = FALSE;
$config['rest_ip_blacklist'] = '';
$config['rest_database_group'] = 'default';
$config['rest_keys_table'] = 'keys';
$config['rest_enable_keys'] = TRUE; //i set it as TRUE default value is FALSE
$config['rest_key_column'] = 'key';
$config['rest_limits_method'] = 'ROUTED_URL';
$config['rest_key_length'] = 40;
$config['rest_key_name'] = 'X-API-KEY';
$config['rest_enable_logging'] = TRUE;//i set it as TRUE default value is FALSE
$config['rest_logs_table'] = 'logs';
$config['rest_enable_access'] = FALSE;
$config['rest_access_table'] = 'access';
$config['rest_logs_json_params'] = FALSE;
$config['rest_enable_limits'] = FALSE;
$config['rest_limits_table'] = 'limits';
$config['rest_ignore_http_accept'] = FALSE;
$config['rest_ajax_only'] = FALSE;
$config['rest_language'] = 'english';
```

Code in routes.php >>

```
$route['api/key/index'] = 'api/key/index'; // Generate First Time Key
```

Can anyone please guide me how to generate this first time key for CI rest server?

It will be really helpful if anyone give solution for this issue asap as i was trying to resolve it since 2 days to find the solution but did not get any success. :(

Answer (score 0):

From that library's repo documentation:

```
//By default, the HTTP will be X-API-KEY. This can be configured in config/rest.php.
$ curl -X POST -H "X-API-KEY: some_key_here" http://example.com/books
```